# CSS - Menu using <ul>

Tags: css

Im in the process of doing my first cutup from PSD to HTML im having a problem styling a menu though.

I have the following code

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

What i want to do is style it like the following

```
Home  |  About  |  Contact
```

How is it possible to get the  | inbetween the elements except before the first?

Im quite confused, any help would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
li { 
list-style-type: none; 
display: inline; 
border-left: 1px solid black; 
padding-left: 10px; 
margin-left: 10px;
}
ul li:first-child {
border-left: none;
}
```

You may notice slight spacing issues in some browsers - meaning the 10px doesn't seem to be the same on each side. You can also float:left each li to remove this, but you'll have to then clear the float after, or have a fixed width and overflow:hidden on the parent container.

Answer (score 1):

```
 li + li::before {
   content: " | ";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an `id` or `class` to the `<ul>` so the CSS rules don't affect every other `<ul>` in the website. Also, the following CSS rules are more suitable as they also work in browsers that don't support `:first-child` and `::before`.

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul#menu li {
    float:left;
    padding:0 2em;
    margin-left:-1px;
    border-left:1px solid #333;
}
```

---

**Demo:** [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/gqJWm](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/gqJWm/)